# Fivestar votes on drupal fields

Tags: 7, entities, rating, media

I'm looking for a drupal module, that allows me to have a fivestar voting for every user (also anonymous) and for every value of a certain field in a node.

What am I trying to do?
I'm trying to have a gallery. Each node with the content-type of "gallery" represents a gallery. In it there is one Image field which allows multiple values. And **each image-value** should be rateable.

Does anyone know such a module for Drupal 7?

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do this easily with the help of three modules
1) Entity
2) Fivestar
3) Field collection

Step 1. Install above modules.
Step 2. Create content type gallery.
Step 3. Add field collection as a field in the content type.
step 4. Add fields(Image field and fivestar field) to the field collection http://www.example.com/admin/structure/field-collections

Comment: So I tried it and managed to upload some images... but I only can vote for all images. But I would like to vote for every single image. Is that possible

Comment: For field collection u can make it multivalued and assign two field to it one will be image and second will be fivestar rating. While creating new gallery u can add multiple field collection. On node view u will be able to see each image will have a fivestar rating associated with it. Means User can vote on each image.

Comment: Are you doing it with field collection or not?

Comment: Ah! Thank you man! The only problem I have now is, that I would like to upload multiple pictures at once :) But that would work for now

Comment: You can upload multiple images at once with field collection. In your content type, edit the field and choose how many items you want for the field like you would for any other field.