# How to use the Rate module to rate things inside the content?

Tags: nodes, rating

I'm quite new to Drupal so I haven't figured out how to use the [Rate](http://drupal.org/project/rate) module for rating things inside the content of, for example, a basic page. I'm using Drupal 7.

Here is what I want to do, but I don't know how:

I have a basic page with links inside the content. I want visitors to be able to vote with thumbs up or down if the link is good. Also I want stars for voting for the contents of the other page. My problem is how to display the thumbs up and stars on my page. Do I create a widget? A view? How do I make them show on my page? A step-by-step explanation would be great!

I've spent so many hours on figuring this out, but I'm sure you can do it in just a few minutes.

Comment: Answered here.. http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/33816/fivestar-votes-on-drupal-fields

Comment: Can it be used to rate users? I only saw where you can rate content types/nodes.

Answer (score 1):

I was also looking how to use the Rate module until I found how. Just:

1. Go to Structure > Rate Widgets.
2. Select the type of rate you want to create and click on Next
3. Enter the information. It allows you to select what type of content will have the new type of rate.

Hope it helps anybody else.

Answer (score 0):

1. Go to content > Add content.
2. In that create content for the Article page.
3. Go to Structure > Rate Widgets.
4. Select the type of rate you want to create and click on Next.
5. Enter the information. It allows you to select what type of content will have the new type of rate.

finally, when you view the content in article page the there appars the rating widgets what you choose